# Android WebView does not display web page correctly

Tags: android

I have simple WebView code like this:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);                  

        wv.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book");
```

But the displayed page shows wikipedia content like as if it was desktop browser which looks pretty ugly on a mobile phone. If I go to wikipedia website on my mobile phone using the browser application, then it displays content correctly according to mobile phone layout.

I tried setting user agent string in webview but that does not help either.

Does any one has solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many sites use JavaScript for browser detection. You need to enable JavaScript for your webview. This works for me:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

wv.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
wv.loadUrl("http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```