# Android WebView does not display web page

Tags: android, android-webview

As stated in this post [Android WebView does not display web page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232332/android-webview-does-not-display-web-page-correctly/6829014#6829014) I have tried javascript enable, but still not working. Have any idea, where i am wrong?

```
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: add internet permission in the manifest file   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @Titus thank you, permission solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` if you haven't done so.
Also check if you have internet connection on your emulator. Try opening the Browser. If you do not have internet connection try to restart the emulator.