# Android WebView does not display web page even though the page has successfully finished loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I have added internet-permissions and I also used the `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` method to check whether the page has loaded which turns out it did. [JavaScript is also enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232332/android-webview-does-not-display-web-page-correctly/6829014#6829014) for my `WebView`.

The code I use to set up my web view

```kotlin
webView.webChromeClient = KeplerWebChromeClient(progressBar)
webView.webViewClient = keplerWebViewClient

webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
webView.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
webView.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
```

I am using `KeplerWebChromeClient` to display web page loading progress.

`keplerWebViewClient` is an object of `WebViewClient` class which I use to load webpages and to track for whether the webpage has finished loading or not.

And I must mention that this issue doesn't always arise. Sometimes when I run my app, the `WebView` does work and it does load and display the web page correctly and other times it doesn't. I have found the below stated **logcat** entries to be unique to when the web page isn't displayed.

> E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(778)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
>
> [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(778)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content  may not draw
>
> E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(778)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
>
> E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(778)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

What is the issue here and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I cleared all the app data from my phone and then I restarted my app. After doing so, everything was working just fine. I was able to browse using the WebView but after using the app a few more times i.e. closing and opening it, the problem reappeared. Clearing all data solves the problem temporarily. What aid can this be in solving the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2683

Answer (score -1):

I have to try and it's working fine for me.

```
private fun setupWebView(url: String) {
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true;
        webView.webViewClient = WebClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = CustomWebChromeClient()
        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }

    private inner class WebClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView,
            url: String
        ): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }
    }

    private inner class CustomWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onJsAlert(
            view: WebView,
            url: String,
            message: String,
            result: JsResult
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
```

I hope it's work for you!

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I don't even know what the cause is. Do you have any idea? Knowing the cause would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to the question. It just shows a lot of unnecessary boilerplate (direct calls to super methods) and doesn't refer to the error log message in any way.